# Conditionally run certbot

Tags: ansible, ssl

I am running an `ansible` task that will among others install a let's encrypt certificate.

I want the task to only run if the certificate has not been installed.

What is the best way to check (via cmd) if my host has a valid secure connection over https?

Comment: Certbot already ensure the certificate has to be renewed or not... why not let it handle that ?

Comment: What role do you use, e.g. http://github.com/030/ansible-certbot

Comment: Did the link help? If not, please post the code you have created.

Answer (score 1):

One could use the `apt` module of Ansible. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/apt_module.html

The `apt` module uses `apt` and apt itself is able to check whether a package has already been installed and will prevent that it will be installed as it has already been installed.

I use this module myself as well. As the idempotence test passes it indicates that it will not install certbot if it has been installed already.

https://github.com/030/ansible-certbot/blob/master/tasks/Debian.yml#L10

```
- name: certbot installed
  apt:
    name: certbot
    state: latest
```